# React - Pass id from array.map to url variable in API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux

Basically i have this array that displays classroom groups and when i press the Button i want so set the variable in my url for my API.

Here is the c

```
const GroupsScreen = () => {
    const [groups, setGroups] = useState([]);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    const [selectedGroup, setSelectedGroup] = useState({});

    const routePick = (group) => {
        setSelectedGroup(group);
        dispatch(routeRequest({id:selectedGroup.id}));
    };


    useEffect(() => {
        getGroupData();
    }, []);

        return (
            <>
                <Container>
                    <CardDeck>
                        {groups.map((group, index) => {
                            return (
                                <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }} key={group.id}>
                                    <Card.Body>
                                        <Card.Title>{group.title}</Card.Title>
                                        <Card.Text>
                                            {group.body}
                                        </Card.Text>
                                        <Button  to="/this_group" onClick={() =>routePick(group)} variant="primary">Entrar</Button>
                                    </Card.Body>
                                </Card>
                            )
                        })}
                    </CardDeck>
                </Container>
            </>
        )
};
```

And this is the api, it calls the list of users for the selected classroom group:

```
    const { route } = useSelector(state => state.routes);
    
    const getUsersData = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch("http://lms.bo.be.test/api/courses/" + route + "/users", {
                method: 'GET'
            });
            const { data } = await response.json();
            setUsers(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
```

Redux config here:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    route: null
}

const routesSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'routes',
    initialState: initialState,
    reducers: {
        routeSet: (state, action) => {
            state.route = action.payload.id;
        },
    },
});

export default routesSlice.reducer;

const { routeSet } = routesSlice.actions;

export const routeRequest = ( {id} ) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch(routeSet({id})); //Se pasa el payload como un objeto, sino solo devuelve el primer valor
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
};
```

The problem im facing is that when i click the Button in Card first it passes and undefined and the second time i click it passes the real value (group id).

Any help is welcome. Also i would like to know what you guys think of this way of coding, if there is anything i can improve in this code.

Edit: Setting the state inside useEffect like this fixed the above problem, like this

```
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(routeRequest({id:selectedGroup.id}));
        getGroupData();
    }, [selectedGroup]);
```

The second issue im facing now is probably a newbie one for sure; when Button redirects to the new screen data doesnt get set in state. If i remove the as={Link} property it does set the state but i need to get redirected to new screen because this is where the API shows the list of users.

Comment: There's some posts floating around regarding this but the general idea is that calling the `setSelectedGroup` function doesn't immediately update the `selectedGroup` state value. You should move your `dispatch()` call into an `useEffect` hook with `selectedGroup` as the dependency

Comment: Thanks Phil, that seems to have fixed the issue. But i have another one, ill update the description.

Comment: I've already closed this as a duplicate. Best to ask in a new question

Comment: Oh, ok, thank you!